# header include in main.cpp works, but throws error in class

Tags: c++, c

I had asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431911/qt-creator-compiles-code-correctly-but-eclipse-throws-error). But the problem seems to be something else so re-posting here..

I am including the header `<zbar.h>` from [Zbar library](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) in main.cpp and the sample code works perfectly fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <zbar.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <cv.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace zbar;
using namespace cv;

int main (int argc, char **argv){
if(argc < 2) return(1);

// create a reader
ImageScanner scanner;

// configure the reader
scanner.set_config(ZBAR_NONE, ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE, 1);

// obtain image data
Magick::Image magick(argv[1]);  // read an image file
int width = magick.columns();   // extract dimensions
int height = magick.rows();
Magick::Blob blob;              // extract the raw data
magick.modifyImage();
magick.write(&blob, "GRAY", 8);
const void *raw = blob.data();

// wrap image data
Image image(width, height, "Y800", raw, width * height);

// scan the image for barcodes
int n = scanner.scan(image);

cv::Mat dispImage = imread(argv[1]);

// extract results
for(Image::SymbolIterator symbol = image.symbol_begin();
    symbol != image.symbol_end();
    ++symbol) {
    // do something useful with results
    cout << "decoded " << symbol->get_type_name()
         << " symbol \"" << symbol->get_data() << '"' << endl;
      }
}
// clean up
image.set_data(NULL, 0);

return(0);
}
```

But if I make a dummy class and include zbar.h in the header of this class, I get the following error :

`the default argument for parameter 0 of ‘zbar::Exception::Exception(const void*)’ has not yet been parsed line 144, external location: /usr/local/include/zbar/Exception.h C/C++ Problem`

```
#ifndef DUMMY_H
#define DUMMY_H

#include <zbar.h>

class dummy{
public:
    dummy();
};

#endif // DUMMY_H
```

I even tried with

```
extern "C"{
    #include <zbar.h>
}
```

but it throws 100s of `template with C linkage` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/api/classzbar_1_1Exception.html), the constructor is declared as

```
Exception(const void * = NULL);
```

The error suggests that `NULL` hasn't been declared; meaning that nothing has included `<cstddef>`. You should be able to fix it by including that yourself, before the evil header.

Comment: Actually i get that as an error too.. `/usr/local/include/zbar/Exception.h:43: error: 'NULL' was not declared in this scope`. Will try it out. Thanks!

Comment: I tried including <cstddef>, <stddef.h> <stdlib.h>, <cstdlib>... But the problem persists!

Comment: But why is it that it works in main.cpp but not in dummy.h? If NULL is undefined, it shouldn't have worked even in main.cpp, right?

Comment: I'm sorry... it worked!!! Couldn't sleep the whole night... but still the question remains... `why is it that it works in main.cpp but not in dummy.h? If NULL is undefined, it shouldn't have worked even in main.cpp, right?`

Comment: @harsh: Your example program includes several other headers; one of them must include `<cstddef>` (directly or indirectly).

Comment: Seymore : Your solution worked... Actually the main.cpp already had iostream included before zbar.h. So that code did not give an error...